# Simple PHP & JSON

Tags: php, file-get-contents, json

I'm having trouble with this script. It works on my local server and test server, but doesn't seem to run correctly on my Rackspace server.

```
<?php

$path = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
$path .= urlencode("SELECT * FROM feed WHERE url='http://feeds.feedburner.com/TMSEvents'");
$path .= "&format=json";

$feed = file_get_contents($path, true);

$feed = json_decode($feed); ?>
```

It is very simple, but I am getting the follow error message on the Rackspace server:

> PHP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT+%2A+FROM+feed+WHERE+url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2FTMSEvents%27&format=json)
>   [function.file-get-contents]:
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 999 This page
>   is currently unavailable

Anyone have any ideas why this would work on one server, but not on another? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a firewall preventing outgoing port-80 requests?

Comment: You might have an outbound firewall or proxy setup... typically an outbound proxy at large providers.

Comment: Indeed, seems like a proxy issue. Unless the remote server is down, which I doubt it is since I can successfully make that request from my browser.

Comment: Try making a request to, for example, `http://www.yahoo.com/` and see if you get the same result. If you do, it's probably a proxy. You could also just ask your host...

Comment: try doing a `wget http://google.com` and see if you get a 500 error or index.html page.

Comment: Thanks guys. Would they be able to just turn it off?

Comment: When I made a request to http://www.yahoo.com the page loaded fine.

Comment: let you, try with cURL. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look on this : http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Try Below code. Its working fine with tested :

```
<?php
$path = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
$path .= urlencode("SELECT * FROM feed WHERE url='http://feeds.feedburner.com/TMSEvents'");
 $path .= "&format=json";
 // Get cURL resource
 $curl = curl_init();
 // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
     CURLOPT_URL => $path,
     CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
 ));
 // Send the request & save response to $resp
 $feed = curl_exec($curl);
 // Close request to clear up some resources
 curl_close($curl);

 $feed = json_decode($feed);
 ?>
```

Comment: i tested this code its working fine for me. Please check this.You have any query than let me know...!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560331/how-to-call-the-json-url-in-php-which-includes-spaces-in-query/16560483#16560483