# How to call the JSON URL in php which includes spaces in query

Tags: php, json

When I was making an xml request to tmdb.org I was using this

```
$movie_name="Dabangg 2";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/accd3ddbbae37c0315fb5c8e19b815a5/"$movie_name"");
```

and it was working !!

Now I have to change the URL since the response is JSON not xml

I have changed it to

```
<?php
$movie_name="Dabangg 2";
$url="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=accd3ddbbae37c0315fb5c8e19b815a5&query=$movie_name";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($json);
?>
```

But it does not work

If you search for

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=accd3ddbbae37c0315fb5c8e19b815a5&query=Dabangg 2
```

on browser you will get the results.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=accd3ddbbae37c0315fb5c8e19b815a5&query=Dabangg 2) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST in /home/wwww/public_html/test/movie.php on line3
```

Please help me

Comment: You have double quotation mark at the end of `$url= ...` line.

Comment: @Wiktor Fixed still getting the same error

`Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=accd3ddbbae37c0315fb5c8e19b815a5&query=Dabangg+2) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable in /home/www/public_html/test/movie.php on line 5
bool(false)`

Comment: maybe you have restrictions on fopen (which internally is used by `file_get_contents()`? Check http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on this : http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Try Below code :

```
<?php
 $movie_name="Dabangg 2";
$movie_name = urlencode($movie_name);
$url="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=accd3ddbbae37c0315fb5c8e19b815a5&query=$movie_name";
 // Get cURL resource
 $curl = curl_init();
 // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,
     CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
 ));
 // Send the request & save response to $resp
 $resp = curl_exec($curl);
 // Close request to clear up some resources
 curl_close($curl);

 var_dump($resp);
 ?>
```

Comment: Is this is running for you ? Try it a, I am getting same error which I was getting before

Comment: Please check now, i updated code with cUrl request. It's working code i cheked on my local system. If you have query let me know..!

Answer (score 5):

Try with

`urlencode($movie_name);`

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a
>   query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next
>   page.